# facebook Page Publish 2

Tags: plugins

I am using acebook Page Publish 2 plugin . which is working fine. but i want to  POST feature image on fb page. but it doesnot showing anything on facebook page.

Does anybody tel me how to POST feature image on fb page

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Add Link to Facebook instead of facebook page publish 2 plugin.It is quite simple plugin.It creates add link to facebook menu under Tools in wordpress admin menu. 
following link below:-
http://wordpress.org/plugins/add-link-to-facebook/

Answer (score 2):

Jetpack is a better plugin for posting to Facebook (and Twitter), it also adds the image automatically to Facebook if it's a featured image.